# create-app creates the application in the current directory

Tags: grails

I'm using the latest Grails version (3.1.12) and following the official [getting started guide](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.12/guide/gettingStarted.html).

I'm stuck at [2.3 Creating an Application](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.12/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication).

```
C:\Users\xehpuk\grails-apps>grails
| Enter a command name to run. Use TAB for completion:
grails> create-app helloworld
| Application created at C:\Users\xehpuk\grails-apps
| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...
```

These are the new contents of `C:\Users\xehpuk\grails-apps`:

```
.gitignore
build
build.gradle
gradle
gradle.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
grails-app
src
```

Obviously, the command [`create-app`](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.12/ref/Command%20Line/create-app.html) creates the app in the current directory instead of the subdirectory `helloworld`, as if I had used the option `--inplace`.

Why and how to change this?

Comment: notice that the `create-app` command is intended to be run from the command line of your OS and not from within the grails shell. e.g. `grails create-app helloworld` and not `grails` then in the shell `create-app helloworld`.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the `create-app` command from within the Grails shell and you shouldn't be.

The `create-app` command should be run from the command line of your OS as such:

`grails create-app helloworld`